# Syntax highlighter in php error unexpected 'code' (T_STRING)

Tags: php, syntax-highlighting

I am creating an online source code judge.I need to display user codes in page with proper syntax highlighting.

I am using the Syntax Highlighter https://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/

I have copied the necessary files in my project.When i try to integrate it with my code i get the following errors :

Snippet of Code :

```
     $result = mysql_query($query); // query to fetch the code
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $str = str_replace("<", "&lt;", $row['soln']); //$row['soln] has the code
        echo("<strong>".$row['filename']."</strong><br/><br/>\n<pre name="code" class="c">".str_replace(">", "&gt;", $str)."</pre>");
    }


?>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="highlight/css/SyntaxHighlighter.css"></link>
<script language="javascript" src="highlight/js/shCore.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="highlight/js/shBrushCSharp.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="highlight/js/shBrushXml.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
dp.SyntaxHighlighter.ClipboardSwf = 'highlight/flash/clipboard.swf';
dp.SyntaxHighlighter.HighlightAll('code');
</script>
```

Error :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'code' (T_STRING) in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/project1/admin/preview.php on line 28

Where am i going wrong? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo("<strong>".$row['filename']."</strong><br/><br/>\n<pre name=\"code\" class=\"c\">".str_replace(">", "&gt;", $str)."</pre>");
```

Replace your echo with the above, you didn't escape some double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo('<strong>'.$row['filename'].'</strong><br/><br/>\n<pre name="code" class="c">'.str_replace(">", "&gt;", $str).'</pre>');
```

or you may try this one also..
no need to escape double quotes.